# It's not displaying the user's text in the MySQL database (TODOapp)

Tags: java, mysql, listener

I'm writing a simple TODO list app in Java (IntelliJ IDEA). The app has a connection with a MySQL database. Everything seems to be fine, but my problem is that the user's text is not being displayed in my database. Instead of the text, it shows either an empty text field or the default text I entered.The same issue in the IntelliJ console(System.out.println).

I think the error might be in the AppFrame class, specifically in the addtask listener or in the addTaskToDatabase method, or I may have incorrectly set the return value in the getter method in the Task class.

My full code is here: https://github.com/lenkZel/TODOapp.git

My mysql database is here:
USE todoapp;
CREATE TABLE tasks(
task_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
task_name VARCHAR(1000),
is_done boolean
);

```
//in AppFrame class:
    public AppFrame() throws SQLException {
            this.setTitle("TODOapp");
            this.setSize(400, 700);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.add(this.title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            this.add(this.btnpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            this.add(this.list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
            addtask = btnpanel.getaddtaskbtn();
            clear = btnpanel.getclearbtn();
            novyText = new JTextField();
            addlistener();
    
            database = new Database();
        }
    public void addlistener() {
            addtask.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    Task task = new Task(novyText.getText());
                    list.add(task);
                    list.indexnum();
                    revalidate();                              
    
                    addTaskToDatabase(task);
    }
    
    public void addTaskToDatabase(Task task) {
            String taskName = task.getTaskname();
            boolean isDone = task.isDone();
    
            String query = "INSERT INTO tasks (task_name, is_done) VALUES (?,?)";
            try {
                PreparedStatement statement = database.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
                statement.setString(1, taskName);
                statement.setBoolean(2, isDone);
                statement.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                System.out.println("Query: " + query);
                System.out.println("Task Name: " + taskName);
                System.out.println("Is Done: " + isDone);
            }
        }
    
    //in Task class:
    taskname = new JTextField(initialText);
            taskname.addFocusListener(this);
            taskname.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 20));
            taskname.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            taskname.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            this.add(this.taskname);
    @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            if (taskname.getText().equals("enter task")) {
                taskname.setText("");
            }
        }
    
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    
    }
    
    public String getTaskname() {
        return taskname.getText();
    }
    
    public boolean isDone() {
        return taskname.getBackground() == Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    }
```

Comment: You need to post code *here* (in any case your repo is empty). As for the code you *have* posted, your table should be called `Task` or `task`. It goes without saying that there might be more than one. The prefix `task_` on your column names is redundant

Comment: it is best to include a [mre] in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but not going to read thriugh all your code. You need to do your debugging first to narrow down the problem and share the relevant code excerpt here.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the code now.

Comment: You need to close that `PreparedStatement` (use try-with-resources) and you should probably pay attention to the return value of `executeUpdate`. Further, it's not a particularly good thing to execute that update in the gui thread, but you might get away with it.

Comment: @g00se it doesn´t work :-(

Comment: int rowsAffected = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (rowsAffected > 0) {
                System.out.println("Task added successfully.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to add task.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } It returns an empty text field

Comment: You also must close the `Connection` eventually. I would actually open and close it for each op. Yes, that's decent code. What is the value of `rowsAffected`?